# MySQL Search and Replace to replace unused shortcodes

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, search, replace

I am updating a Wordpress site. It used a shortcode to produce youtube embed videos, but that's not really needed anymore. I'm a front end dev and I want to be careful before touching the Database. How can I use a MySQL Search and Replace to transform:

```
[sc:youtube id="abcdefghijk"]
```

where `abcdefghijk` is the youtube video id. I'd like to transform it into a standard embed code like this:

```
<iframe width="775" height="436" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/abcdefghijk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The only thing that really needs to be carried over is the id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with Wordpress but the MySQL statement would be as follows. Assuming the table is named meta_data and the columns are meta_key, meta_value where meta_key would have youtube and the meta_value would have abcdefghijk.  Change the column and table names to whatever the real information is.

```
UPDATE 
    `meta_data`
SET
    `meta_value` = CONCAT('<iframe width="775" height="436" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/', meta_value, '?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
WHERE
    `meta_key` = 'youtube'
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite interesting question. but I'm afraid that this can't be done in MySQL with REPLACE or with REGEXP syntax. So I wrote a small wordpress plugin for regular expression search and replace on posts. Before using the plugin make sure to backup the `wp_posts` table.

```
CREATE TABLE wp_posts_temp LIKE wp_posts; 
INSERT INTO wp_posts_temp SELECT * FROM wp_posts;
```

**plugin code**

Put this code into file like replace.php inside wp-content/plugins/replace-in-posts/ folder, and activate the plugin.

```
<?php
/* 
Plugin Name: Replace in posts
Author: Danijel
*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'replace_in_posts_menu');
function replace_in_posts_menu() {
    add_options_page("Replace in posts", "Replace in posts", 'manage_options', "replace_in_posts", "replace_in_posts_admin");
}

function replace_in_posts_admin() {
    if ( !empty($_POST['pattern']) && isset($_POST['replacement']) ) {
        $pattern = stripslashes_deep( $_POST['pattern'] );
        $replacement = stripslashes_deep( $_POST['replacement'] );
        $count = replace_in_posts( '/'.$pattern.'/', $replacement );
    }
    ?><div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"></div><h2><?php echo 'Replace in posts' ?></h2>
    <div class="wrap"><form method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url()."admin.php?page=".$_GET["page"] ?>">
        Pattern (without delimiter) : <input type="text" name="pattern" value="">
        Replacement: <input type="text" name="replacement" value="">
        <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Replace" >
    </form><?php if (isset($pattern)) : ?><p>Pattern "<?php echo $pattern; ?>" replaced in <?php echo ( $count ? $count : '0' ); ?> posts</p><?php endif; ?></div><?php
}

function replace_in_posts( $pattern, $replacement ) {
    $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1');
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) {
        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $post->post_content ) ) {
            $post->post_content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $post->post_content  );
            wp_update_post( $post );
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
?>
```

Regular expression pattern and replacement for your question:

```
\[sc:youtube id="(\w+?)"\]
<iframe width="775" height="436" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Plugin has been tested on that pattern and there were no errors.